# Terraform Cellular Architecture

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I am just getting started with Terraform. From what I have found online, there don't seem to be many examples (or any that I have found so far) of coding out a cellular infrastructure model.

The idea is to follow something like https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/guidance/cell-based-architecture-on-aws/

Basically, I am looking to create a few different infrastructure sets and how I would relate them as ideally you would want to manage them in separate packages but still be related / able to reference each other. Can anyone help recommend some resources or references like this?

My other question comes down to how to deploy a repeated infra in multiple accounts for the cells themselves. My guess so far from reading would be to create a module for the cell and then feed it a provider for each account. Does that approach sound reasonable, or is there something I am missing?

Apologies if these are very simple questions. Just getting started with Terraform.